# How to write a JSON file without overlapping previous data

Tags: java, json

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class writejson {
    //public static void writejs(String attachmentValue)
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String attachmentValue= "1234";
        {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("Attachement Id: ", attachmentValue);
            try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("C:\\failedtestdata.json"))
            {
                file.write(obj.toJSONString());
                file.flush();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In JSON file without overlapping the existing record. How to create a new records on next line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Use Append true constructor - Like FileWriter("C:\failedtestdata.json",true)
2.Add \n to every write, So append will start at the next line by default

Comment: It is working but its look like a invalid JSON.                                                        {"Attachement Id: ":"12"}{"Attachement Id: ":"1234"}{"Attachement Id: ":"1234"}{"Attachement Id: ":"1234"}{"Attachement Id: ":"1234"}.How we can make it as valid Json @Srini

Comment: Instead of \n , you could use ,.
Anyway For this to be valid, the overall schema has to be jsonarray

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class WriteJson {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String attachmentValue= "1234";
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("Attachement Id: ", attachmentValue);
        String loc="C:\\failedtestdata.json";
        try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter(loc,true))
        {
         //File Writer creates a file in write mode at the given location 
         file.write(obj.toJSONString());
         file.write(",");
         file.append("\n");
         file.flush();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```